# Android - Gridview behaves crazy

Tags: android, gridview, lazy-loading

I have a `CustomGrid` for a Product Catalog. The data for the Grid is stored local. The Text comes from a local JSON File and the images are also stored under `res`.

While displaying the GridView the 300 items are not arranged properly. They repeat after 20 entries and they mix up when I scroll up and down.

I debugged the data arrays but they look fine. I also have the same image path for every item right now. So every Gridview item  has the same image. But thats no different behavior of the GridView.

I have no problems on other Gridviews with much less items. I read about lazy loading, but I am not downloading the image files

Why is the Grid behaving like this? Is this too much overload at once? How can I solve this problem?

EDIT:

CustomGrid:

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private final String[] gridItemText;
private final int[] imageID;

public CustomGrid(Context c, String[] gridItemText, int[] imageID){
    mContext = c;
    this.gridItemText = gridItemText;
    this.imageID = imageID;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return gridItemText.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        //grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single_main, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_single_text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_single_image);
        textView.setText(gridItemText[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageID[position]);
    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    return grid;
}

}
```

Activity:

```
CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(ProductCatalogActivity.this, menuData, imagePath);
    gridView1=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_Main);
    gridView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            //ToDo
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please add some code

Comment: I added the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in place of your Viewholder mechanism

```
   TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        //grid = new View(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single_main, null);
        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_single_text);
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_single_image);
        convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(textView, imageView));
    } else {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        textView = viewHolder.textView;
        imageView = viewHolder.imageView;

    }

    textView.setText(gridItemText[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageID[position]);
return convertView;
```

also use this viewholder

```
 private static class ViewHolder {

        public final TextView textView;
        public final ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(TextView textView, ImageView imageView) {
            this.textView = textView;
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well my guess is that the view holder that you were using was not properly handling the objects, For instance there was no Object reference retaining mechanism such as the setTag() or equivalent so the state of the objects might be changing because of that.